# PHP get names in a file after letters name:

Tags: php, string

I need a PHP script to print customer names in a file.  There's hundreds of names and addresses but I want to print only the names with a maximum of 15 letters.

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents('data-cust.txt');
$keyword = 'name';
$str = substr($file, strpos($file, $keyword) + strlen($keyword), 15);
echo $str;
?>
```

I tried using the above but only printed one name.  How do I make it print all names?
Thanks.

Comment: How are the names arranged in the file? One per line?

Comment: example: 1. Michael Berkowski, Address : xxxx xxx, Phone :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the names are on their own line, something like this should work.

```
<?php
$file = file('data-cust.txt');
foreach($file as $line) {
    $keyword = 'name';
    $str = substr($line, strpos($line, $keyword) + strlen($keyword), 15);
    echo $str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the file and read it then extract the names.

```
$file = fopen("data-cust.txt", "r");
$keyword = 'name';
$str = array() ;
if ($file) {
    while (($line = fgets($file )) !== false) {
        $name = substr($line, strpos($line, $keyword) + strlen($line), 15);
       echo $name ;
        $str[] = $name ;
    }
} else {
    // error opening file
} 
fclose($file );

print_r($str) ;
```